# ANR - Cause: null pointer dereference

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-anr-dialog

I am getting one ANR when app is ideal for some minutes in foreground mode. This screen is having text input box (signup process). here I am just filling whole form and keeping app in ideal state. then getting this ANR and app closes that screen and came back to previous screen.

```
2022-02-11 15:14:50.568 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/MAR-LX2/HWMAR:10/HUAWEIMAR-L22A/10.0.0.279C675:user/release-keys'
2022-02-11 15:14:50.568 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2022-02-11 15:14:50.568 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2022-02-11 15:14:50.568 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2022-02-11 17:44:50+0800
2022-02-11 15:14:50.568 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG: pid: 31015, tid: 31028, name: HeapTaskDaemon  >>> com.feo <<<
2022-02-11 15:14:50.568 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG: uid: 11298
2022-02-11 15:14:50.569 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
2022-02-11 15:14:50.569 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2022-02-11 15:14:50.569 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:     x0  00000071c16bd400  x1  00000071b5e13a98  x2  0000000000000008  x3  0000000070f38b10
2022-02-11 15:14:50.569 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:     x4  000000000000044c  x5  000000001338ca2c  x6  12c4274012c42f58  x7  0000000070f61c80
2022-02-11 15:14:50.569 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:     x8  0000000000000000  x9  cdaede85033c2750  x10 0000000052c00000  x11 0000000000000008
2022-02-11 15:14:50.569 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:     x12 000000000000000b  x13 000009fd00000071  x14 0006ae0246258983  x15 0000126e86b54941
2022-02-11 15:14:50.569 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:     x16 00000071c15fb000  x17 0000007242f42b40  x18 000000715d798000  x19 00000071b5e13a98
2022-02-11 15:14:50.569 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000000070f38b10  x21 0000000000000008  x22 00000000716ab790  x23 00000000716aa070
2022-02-11 15:14:50.569 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000000000000028  x25 0000000000002828  x26 00000071b5e15020  x27 0000000000001720
2022-02-11 15:14:50.569 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:     x28 00000000716aa088  x29 00000071b5e13a80
2022-02-11 15:14:50.569 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:     sp  00000071b5e13a10  lr  00000071c1236f6c  pc  00000071c1236f48
2022-02-11 15:14:50.723 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 000000000022ff48  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6mirror6Object15VisitReferencesILb1ELNS_17VerifyObjectFlagsE0ELNS_17ReadBarrierOptionE1ENS_2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying16RefFieldsVisitorILb0EEES9_EEvRKT2_RKT3_+2828) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 000000000021fd10  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::ImmuneSpaceScanObjVisitor::Callback(art::mirror::Object*, void*)+112) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 000000000020e188  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::accounting::ModUnionTableReferenceCache::VisitObjects(void (*)(art::mirror::Object*, void*), void*)+292) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 000000000021a9dc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::CopyingPhase()+1236) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 00000000002188c4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::RunPhases()+1148) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 0000000000236f48  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::collector::GarbageCollector::Run(art::gc::GcCause, bool)+288) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 0000000000255fd4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::CollectGarbageInternal(art::gc::collector::GcType, art::gc::GcCause, bool)+3196) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 000000000026838c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ConcurrentGC(art::Thread*, art::gc::GcCause, bool)+124) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 000000000026df58  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::ConcurrentGCTask::Run(art::Thread*)+36) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 000000000029b2f8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::gc::TaskProcessor::RunAllTasks(art::Thread*)+64) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 0000000000067aec  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (art_jni_trampoline+124) (BuildId: cd6043ddfff407b4835c3e45be96dbab5a0b3a9b)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 0000000000144334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 00000000001531a4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+252) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #13 pc 00000000002ee6d8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+384) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #14 pc 00000000002e99a8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+912) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #15 pc 00000000005bb284  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+648) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #16 pc 000000000013e814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #17 pc 00000000001b47c2  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar (java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal+38)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #18 pc 00000000005bb594  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1432) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #19 pc 000000000013e814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #20 pc 00000000001b3fa6  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+50)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #21 pc 00000000005bcd94  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1752) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #22 pc 000000000013ea14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #23 pc 00000000000eabdc  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.Thread.run+8)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #24 pc 00000000002bf314  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.17950311261770437987+240) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #25 pc 00000000005a6470  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1012) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #26 pc 000000000014d468  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #27 pc 0000000000144334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #28 pc 00000000001531a4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+252) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #29 pc 00000000004c6ec0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #30 pc 00000000004c7f54  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+416) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #31 pc 0000000000507f24  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1176) (BuildId: 602edb11a79b9a18b1585382d06c7450)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #32 pc 00000000000ce1b0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36) (BuildId: 95e03d8a9f101c0f1d3d9458688aa085)
2022-02-11 15:14:50.724 32014-32014/? A/DEBUG:       #33 pc 0000000000070ba8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 95e03d8a9f101c0f1d3d9458688aa085)
```

**Anyone having any idea what I need to check or monitor in app for this ? any code level changes I can make in this case ?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a similiar error from here: https://blog.csdn.net/zgz9949/article/details/111641415

It gave out a solution: delete the folder `/data/local/tmp/perfd`. You can backup it if you are worried about the result.